# RESTful service with JAX-RS Create method responce

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jax-rs

I'm developing a RESTful service using Java EE Jax-RS. I got my basic codes forward engineered with Netbeans.

The return type of `create` method in AbstractFacade which all my Resource Facades inherits is void.

```
public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }
```

This is my ComplainFacadeREST

```
@POST
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void  create( Complain entity ) {
    super.create(entity);
}
```

Therefore it does not send any useful response once a resource is created. Instead I get a `204 No Content` response. But this is not how it should happen, right?

> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location header

What should I do now? Getting no response seems a problem, I have to redirect the user to `#/resource/:id` in my AngularJS UI. For that, either I have to send the id of the newly created resource or send a correct Location header. May I change the AbstractFacade? Or is there any other way? Or have I missed something? People who have created `AbstractFacade` in Netbeans has marked `create` method as `void` for a good reason?

Answer (score 1):

You should return a response object, e.g.

```
URI uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().build(entity.getId());
return Response.created(uri).build();
```

Comment: That means I have to change the return type to Response from void, right? Why they have marked it as void? Any special reason? I have to change this in AbstractFacade and then change every child class. Are you sure this is the best method?

Comment: Who is they?  This is the way I would recommend.

Comment: Actually, I generated the base classes. People who have developed this Netbeans' Forward engineering module for JAX-RS should have a good reason to mark `Create` method `void`, right? I have to change `AbstractFacade` to return a `Response`, that's what bothers me. Why it is `void` there? (`AbstractFacade` is an autogenerated class) BTW, your answer is very useful, didn't know about UriBuilder! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return 201, why not add an abstraction around the `create()` method? Add a new layer in between and return 201 from that layer/class.